# How can i display 3 post types in same page?

Tags: php, search

How can i display  3 post types in same page search results.

http://cinema.trancelevel.com/

For example i have

post_type1-Movies
post_type2-Trailers
post_type3-Subtitrari

Wen i search i want to display the search results..

Ex: i Search for Battleship Movie.

I want the search results to display somting like this

1.)The movie:
Battleship

2.)The Trailers:
- Battleship HD
- Battleship Trailer Oficial

3.)The News
All the news that contain the word Battleship.

Or.. how can i display for each post_type diferent themplate...

EX:
For Movies it show fine:

-http://cinema.trancelevel.com/?s=Battleship&post_type=post

For Trailers it show the teme of movies:

-http://cinema.trancelevel.com/?s=Battleship&post_type=trailers

Wath i use in Search

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<input class="search_input" type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Cauta filme, subtitrari, trailere, stiri" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
    <select name="post_type" class="search_select">
        <option value="post">Alege:</option>
        <option value="post">Filme</option>
        <option value="persoane">Actori</option>
        <option value="trailers">Trailere</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="search_buton" value="Cauta" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your registration arguments for your post types have the `public` argument set to *true* or, alternately, `publicly_queryable` set to *true* and `exclude_from_search` set to *false*.

Then, modify your search query by hooking into the `pre_get_posts` action:

```
function filter_search( $query ) {
    $postTypes = array( 'post', 'post_type1-Movies', 'post_type2-Trailers', 'post_type3-Subtitrari' );

    //Here you can modify the $postTypes array, say to account for the value of $_REQUEST['post_type'] as set by your dropdown or some such.

    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', $postTypes );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_search' );
```

Now all of your custom post types will be included in search queries.

If you wish to group multiple post types relating to the same subject, however (i.e. a specific movie or some such), it may be wiser to only search the post-type of the primary subject (i.e. searching for "Battleship" would only search your movie post-type). Associating other post types with the subject could be done by storing the primary subject's id in the meta-data for each associated item. This would allow you to query each of the other post types for associated data by simply searching for the primary subject's id, ideally when displaying it from within the loop (i.e. when looping through the results of the "Battleship" search, query the trailers post type for items with a meta field, "movie" set to the ID of the movie post currently being processed).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to alter the wp_query on your search page to accept `'post_type' => $_get['post_type']` - this will grab your dropdown selection.

Check out [Creating a Search Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) in the codex for how to create/customize a search results page, and the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class for how to create a custom query.

Comment: Please use the WYSIWG editor for code formatting. Thanks.

Comment: can you paste the code here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this could be done. I've thought about doing this for a project of mine.

1. If you want to have the different post types grouped together then have an initial loop that separates the posts by post type into different arrays, then use a different template for each array.
2. If you want list the results all together but want to denote which is which then in your loop you check for post type then use the appropriate template via the `get_template_part` function

Comment: hy Manny Fleurmod thanks for reply, can you explayn more please... i do not undestand... i make point 1 it work but plese see the link now, but i want to search to all custom field same time and retrive in same page , Movie, Trailers, news... that contain the Word Battleship...