# How can i retrive the movies, trailers, news in a single page using search

Tags: posts, php, search, custom-post-type-archives, customization

How can i retrive that. For a few month i build a website, and i want to make it diferent

For the search i have 3 post type, and i have for each diferent themes for display
- Movies
- Trailers
- Persons

[image: How can]

How i retrive the theme's

```
<?
/* Template Name: Search Results */
$search_refer = $_GET["post_type"];
if ($search_refer == 'post') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search/search-filme.php'); }
if ($search_refer == 'persoane') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search/search-actori.php'); }
if ($search_refer == 'serial') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search/search-seriale.php'); }
elseif ($search_refer == 'trailers') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search/search-trailers.php'); };
?>
```

So i want to be able to search for a movie and retrive the trailers and the movie in same page each under and search without selecting the post type. as seen on top of a picture.

The Search of movies

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php
        $args = array(
                'post_type'=> 'post',
                's'    => $s);
                query_posts($args);
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
//....
```

Trailers

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $args = array('post_type'=> 'trailers', 's'    => $s); query_posts($args); ?>
...
```

Thanks in andvance to thouse who help me to achive this.

Comment: suspiciously similar to this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90752/how-to-build-a-search-filter

Comment: Not to mention this one, wherein I actually described a solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64303/how-can-i-display-3-post-types-in-same-page/78174#78174 . If your question was not answered in your previous posts and remains essentially unchanged, please go back and edit your original post rather than continuing to create new posts.